# How to open and close div element while cliking of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my html format i want to open `leftbar` div tag while clicking of `open-left` tag and also close `leftbar` div tag while clicking of `open-left` tag.

```
    <div id="leftbar" class="snap-drawers">
            <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <img src="assets/img/nloop-min.png" alt="" class="drawer-logo" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"></i>&emsp;Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-1x"></i>&emsp;Tour</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-1x"></i>&emsp;FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-1x"></i>&emsp;About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-1x"></i>&emsp;Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        &copy; 2013 - nLoop</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="snap-content">
                <div id="sidebarmenu" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" id="open-left"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="rightpart" class="margingap">
            Right part
                </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var snapper = new Snap({
                element: document.getElementById('content'),
                disable: 'right'
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var addEvent = function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
    }
};

addEvent(document.getElementById('open-left'), 'click', function () {

    snapper.open('left');

        var state = $(this).is('.open');
       if (state) {
            snapper.close('left');
        }
});

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: I don't see any js code in your question, have you missed to post it?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7M3xV/2/

Answer (score 2):

Open and close div element while cliking an anchor tag:

```
$("#open-left").click(function(){
    $("#leftbar").toggle();
});
```

See more about this here: [.toggle() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**Code explanation:**

I am just attaching a click event to the `#open-left` tag and then I called the `.toggle()` on the `#leftbar`. This just pretty much keeps record of what is the current state of the object, hiddden or shown, and then calls the particular function according to the state.

Also, see this working example: [<kbd>fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FBuE6/).

Comment: i want to open div tag and close also same tag when clicking of only one anchor tag.

Comment: @JeetBhatt Have you tried my code? it's doing the same I think.

Comment: @JeetBhatt so what changes do I need to make in my current code? :O

Comment: how to use snapper.close('left'); or snapper.open('left'); instead of toggle()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for something like jQuery's [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)? Or [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isOpen = false;
$("#open-left").click(function(){
    if(isOpen){
       $("#leftbar").slideUp(); isOpen = false;}
    else{ $("#leftbar").slideDown(); isOpen = true; }
});
```